# Trouble with using Selenium Webriver features

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

i didn`t find any useful info about my problem. sorry if i repeat.

for example i want to click at the main page of http://www.bbc.com/ in the bottom of site link "Mobile site". in casual i do smth like this, to click on my button:

> *driver.getMouse(driver.findElement(By.Id("blq-footer-mobile"))).click();*

but now i need to simulate the activity of user.
1. i need to scroll the page to bottom
2. need to move the cursor on link
3. click it

i realy tried all what i found in the internet, but everything wrong.

Comment: I cannot try your example myself, but I think WebDriver tries to scroll automatically if you use `driver.findElement(By.Id("blq-footer-mobile")).click()`. For helping the scrolling, see this discussion: http://www.seleniumwebdriver.com/google-selenium-webdriver/scroll-automatically-before-click-feature-or-not/

Answer (score 0):

`WebDriver` simulates user interactions with web applications using native browser APIs. So as long as you are using pure `WebDriver API`, you are simulating natural user. You don't need to explicitly scroll, `WebDriver` would do that for you. If it's not scrolling then it is a bug and please report it accordingly. As for your question, here is the code that works.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.bbc.com/");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("blq-footer-mobile"));
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Mobile site** link in the above website will just take u to **UK website of BBC**..

which means, a click on **Mobile site** link  in http://www.bbc.com/ will actually lead you to http://www.bbc.co.uk/, where in the page remains same with just the URL changed..

if you really want to experiment on **Mobile site** link, use this URL :  http://www.bbc.co.uk/

you can try the following **code :**

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.bbc.co.uk/");
new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("blq-footer-mobile"))).click();
```

this will wait for elements visibility and click on it,and this will take you to **actual mobile site of BBC**..